# Concurrent LOAD DATA INFILE and DELETE

Tags: mysql, performance, load-data-infile

I have a table `Calls` with 3 columns: `messageType`, `callId` and `lastModified`.

For each call, 4 rows are written in the DB, one for each message. There are 4 types of messages: **CALL-SETUP**, **CALL-PROGRESS**, **CALL-START** and **CALL-STOP** (code 4).

The columns `messageType` and `callId` compose the primary key.

I want to delete the following rows:

- the rows corresponding to a terminated call. A call is terminated when the CALL-STOP message has been written in the DB.
- the rows that have not been modified since 4 hours (for example).

I used the following query:

```
DELETE FROM Calls WHERE callId IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT callId FROM Calls WHERE messageType=4 OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,lastModified,NOW()) > 14400) AS tmp);
```

I use this statement only to clean the table. But, at the same time, the table is also populated very frequently (e.g. every second) by large files (around 30000 rows) using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and I really see a difference in terms of perfomance between only loading data and loading data + clean.

What can I do to improve performance? on the SQL DELETE? on the DB itself?

I precise that I use MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Which storage engine does your `Calls` table use?

Comment: @eggyal It's a new table, so I can choose the storage engine to use. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: How can you witness a performance degradation on a table that does not yet exist?

Comment: @eggyal By "new table", I meant that I have the choice to chose any storage engine I want. I've done my tests after creating this table, but changing it will not affect anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts for you:

1) I really hate DISTINCT.  Does each call only have one messageType of 4?  If so, you're using the DISTINCT for the modified portion of the OR clause.  How about this:

```
 WHERE messageType = 4
 OR (messageType = 1 and lastModified < datesub(now(), interval 4 hour)
```

(so you'll only get one ID back and there's no need to DISTINCT them).

2) Don't run formulas on your date column - the engine can't use an index!  See my WHERE clause above for moving the formula to the other side, where it can use the index and the constant value can be cached.

3) You don't describe your indexes, but you'd probably want a composite index on (lastModified, messageType, callId).

4) As others have stated, engine choice does matter.  myisam locks everything.  Try innodb.

5) Sometimes MySQL doesn't like date indexes for large ranges of dates.  Try using a script to delete small batches.

Good luck!